# Spring data mongoDb controller how can I update document as a field in side document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have document as a field in side another document how can I update in it

Models:

```
@Document(collection = "maladies")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Malady {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nom;
    @DBRef
    private Organ organ;
}


@Document(collection = "organs")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Organ {//organe Document
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String nom;
}
```

Repositorys

```
public interface MaladyRepository extends MongoRepository<Malady, String> {
}


public interface OrganRepository extends MongoRepository<Organ, String> {
}
```

Controller
I use this method to update all field but doesn’t work with the organ document field
My question is how can I update organ document as a field?

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/maladies/{id}")
    public Malady update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Malady malady) {
        Optional<Malady> optionalMalady = maladyRepository.findById(id);
        Malady m = optionalMalady.get();
        if(malady.getNom() != null)
            m.setNom(malady.getNom());
        if(malady.getOrgan() != null)
            m.setOrgan(malady.getOrgan());
        maladyRepository.save(m);
        return m;
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, using Malady m = optionalMalady.get(); without checking that te optional actually has a value isn't a good idea.

You should better check that the value is present first, before calling`get()`. Your null check will not help in case if optional is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the document in the `organs` collection.
Because you reference it.

Annotation `@DbRef` only resolves the dependency document during reading.

Mapping framework doesn't handle cascading operations. So – for instance – if we trigger a save on a parent, the child won't be saved automatically – we'll need to explicitly trigger the save on the child if we want to save it as well.

In order to solve your problem, you can consider using the lifecycle events listeners.
It is quite common to use them in combination with `@DbRef`

```
public class OrganCascadeSaveMongoEventListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {
    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeConvert(BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) { 
        Object source = event.getSource(); 
        if ((source instanceof Malady) && (((Malady) source).getOrgan() != null)) { 
            mongoOperations.save(((Malady) source).getOrgan());
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add this listener to your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public OrganCascadeSaveMongoEventListener  organCascadeSaveMongoEventListener() {
        return new OrganCascadeSaveMongoEventListener();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where I add this class in model or controller or what?

Comment: @Lili lillas Just create this class and update your configuration to add this listener to context.